# Buildings displaying without texture in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api

[image]Buildingins in google maps displaying without image and texture. I have this problem only when I use https protocol, when I use http everything fine. Sombody know what could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

ok, i fix it. In my case, when i use my own style for google map, i set style for landscape

```
"featureType": "landscape",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "on" },
      { "color": "#dacbc4" }
    ]
```

and that was a problem.